# Binding to ajax:success Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have the following HTML form in my Rails app:

```
#views/foods/index.html.erb
<%= form_tag foods_path, remote: true, method: :get do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:query] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Aminoize!", name: nil %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

My controller is set up to respond to the AJAX request with JSON:

```
#controllers/foods_controller.rb
def index
  if params[:search]
    @foods = Food.search(params[:search])
    render json: @foods
  end
end
```

I want to handle the response with my client side Javascript, thus I am attempting to bind to the ajax:success event like so:

```
#foods/views/index.js.erb
$('#search').on('ajax:success', function(data) {
  alert("This works!");
  //eventually do something with data here
});
```

And my server log indicates the server is responding with 200:

```
Started GET "/foods?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=edamame" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-05 16:38:37 -0800
Processing by FoodsController#index as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "search"=>"edamame"}
Food Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "foods".* FROM "foods"  WHERE (name @@ '%edamame%')
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 5.7ms)
```

However, my alert is never triggering. I figure I must be binding to the AJAX event incorrectly, but I am unsure why. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try this it may work: `$(document).on('ajaxSuccess','#search',function(){
   alert("This works!");
});`

Comment: Shouldn't you be binding the `ajax:success` event to the form tag since you specified `{remote: true}` to it?

Comment: I tried "$('form').on('ajax:success', function(data)" but that did not work either. Is that what you meant by bind ajax:success to the form tag?